# Excel Insert new data row from cell that changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have tried searching but am having trouble with the correct terminology to get a good result.

I am looking for a way or for advice to create a macro in excel that will copy data from one cell and insert it into a new row each time it changes.

I would like to be able to accumulate a history of about 50 data changes.

thanks
Jeff

Comment: That might be possible. It would require A) a way to run a macro each time the cell contents changes and B) another cell which stores the "next row" number; then each time you insert text, you increment the stored row number.

Comment: Have you looked into Excel's built in Tracking options? Check this article from Microsoft and see if it applies to your situation: [Track Changes in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Track-changes-in-a-Shared-Workbook-22aea671-cac7-4fa3-845d-eeb23725bd15)

Comment: Does the cell contain a **formula** or a **user-entered** value ??

Comment: @jrichall I don't think that's what he wants. Instead, try looking for [Workbook_Change event](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm). There's a good amount of examples here and on internet, at this moment I can't search.

Comment: @Vylix Workbook_Change would work as well. It also wouldn't be a bad introduction to VBA if OP hasn't used it before. I've used the tracking option in a shared workbook to generate a sheet showing changes over a 30 day (I think...been a while) period. If you turn off the highlighting, it doesn't effect the "look" of the table, but lists all the changes on a separate sheet. The file was stored on a SharePoint site, so it made it easier to track changes to data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick snippet to get you started and give you some things to search for. This code will watch cell A1 and if it changes it will record the time it changes and the value it takes after changing in row 3. This will probably take some additional logic to be useful. The code goes in the VBA code for the sheet which is changing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'WatchedCell is the cell we want to log changes of, I used cell A1
    Dim WatchedCell As Range
    Set WatchedCell = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    'Target comes from the Worksheet_Change event and tells us what changed in the event
    'See if the watched cell is among the cells which changed
    Dim Inter As Range
    Set Inter = Intersect(WatchedCell, Target)

    'Insert a row to record the time in the column A and the value after the change in column B
    If Not Inter Is Nothing Then
        Rows(3).EntireRow.Insert
        Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A3") = Now()
        Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B3") = WatchedCell
    End If
End Sub
```

One important issue (implied by Gary's Student in the comments to your question) is that if, for example, cell A1 is a formula and only changes when cell A2 changes, the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event does not recognize A1 as having changed when you change A2 because it changed due to the Worksheet_Calculate event.